# printf("%s") returns symbols

Tags: c, printf

Doing K&R exercise 1-16, and want to simply printf the contents of a char array.

```
#define MAXLINE 1000        /* max num of input chars */
char longest[MAXLINE];      /* char array to hold longest input */

...get input, store, calculate longest input line...

printf("Length : %d, Text was : %s\n", max, longest);
```

I get this as output:

[image: shell output from C program]

What should I be doing to print the text, and are those unicode characters?

PS. I searched everywhere...

Comment: What are you storing in the character array? Show us the modifications to the array you make.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3686966 - gist of the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
(c = getchar() != EOF)
```

to

```
(c = getchar()) != EOF
```

Your version sets c to 1 for every character read, and to 0 for eof.